# how do i fix opencart checkout error?

Tags: php

I am using opencart, I recently moved my eCommerce website to a new host, everything worked fine, the only problem I have now is that after adding items to cart and I click check out at the front store, I am taken to `mydomainindex.php/?route=checkout/checkout` instead of `mydomain/index.php/?route=checkout/checkout`.

**Please note the /**

How can I fix the error? My old website was working perfectly until I moved the site to a new host.

Comment: missing slash in some config file at a guess

Comment: How can i fix it? i really need help asap

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccess file to make sure you have

`RewriteBase /`

Comment: RewriteBase / is there